# Elasticsearch | list all routing

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to get all the routings I have already used to index different documents? For example I am using month to define the routing. All documents with value as July in response date would be moved to a single shard and so on. Now can I get all the months which are used as Routing value through some query?